# Apache HttpClient ResponseHandler Exceptions

Tags: java, apache, http, exception

```
ResponseHandler<RedditRequestResponse> rh = new ResponseHandler<RedditRequestResponse>() {
            @Override
            public RedditRequestResponse handleResponse(
                    final HttpResponse response) throws IOException, RedditException {
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity == null) {
                    throw new ClientProtocolException("Response contains no content");
                }
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    throw new RedditException(generateErrorString(statusCode, input, responseBody));
                }               

                return new RedditRequestResponse(statusCode, responseBody);
            }
        };
```

I'd like to throw my own `RedditException` from `handleResponse()` that includes the response body. However, when I try that (like in the above code) I get a `RedditException not compatible with throws clause` error. I suspect this has something to do with the @Override. What exactly is being overridden? The class that contains this method does not inherit from any other class and does not implement any interfaces that I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your `RedditException` extend an `IOException` then you will be able to get around it by keeping the same method signature